# Yii2: trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I want to list all distinct records from create_client table, and have tried this code but am getting an error.

What's wrong with this code?

```
    $query = new Query;
    $ccname = (new yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['id','company_name','client_code'])
    ->from('create_client')
    ->distinct()
    ->all();

     $sidemenus = mysql_fetch_array($ccname);
     echo $sidemenu['company_name']."<br />";
```

Update-

Got the desired result by this-

```
$posts = $db->createCommand('SELECT DISTINCT company_name,client_code FROM create_client')
            ->queryAll();
         var_dump($posts)
```

But how to convert this in to string so that I can use on page?

Comment: i guess you have wrong order. ->distinct() is after select not from .. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

Comment: you pass $ccname query into mysql_fetch_array but it expect resource not array. Try use print_r($ccname) what it returns. You don't need use mysql_fetch_array

Comment: '$posts = $db->createCommand('SELECT DISTINCT company_name,client_code FROM create_client')
            ->queryAll();
         var_dump($posts)'
got this working but how to convert this array into string?

Comment: convert array to string? what you need do that? what you want to get? Can you post result of $posts ?

Comment: ya I actually  want to list all distinct **company_name** and there corresponding **client_code**.

Comment: post your DUMP please. We not have your data.

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["company_name"]=> string(7) "Metro" ["client_code"]=> string(8) "12345678" } [1]=> array(2) { ["company_name"]=> string(6) "3D Services" ["client_code"]=> string(6) "159827" } }

Comment: ok you have two results because your data are not equals. Which you want?

Comment: need to create list of all distinct comapny_name and corresponding client_code, both the results

Comment: but DISTINCT in sql is COLUMN duplicity... eg. if you have in one column COL many same values eg. Company1 ... distinct do only one record from duplicitates... but your distinct working fine but your values are different !!

Comment: actually I made my client_code column unique user can not add duplicate client_code in records.

Comment: you have list of all ... list = array in your case if you want to print out you need to use foreach loop because you have many records not one

Comment: will you write this function, actually new to Yii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try your query modified like that

```
$query = new yii\db\Query();
$data = $query->select(['id','company_name','client_code'])
    ->from('create_client')
    ->distinct()
    ->all();
```

the important part is **all()** method because it execute your query and return result as array

> all() Executes the query and returns all results as an array.

then you can work with result as normal array

```
if($data) {
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        echo 'company_name: ' . $row['company_name'] . ' client_code: ' . $row['client_code'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

[documentation yii2 - class yii\db\Query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html)

Comment: one question, how can I render this from controller to view?

Comment: if you are new you should read start guide and try it... more things make sense to you after that. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html

Comment: but how to pass this foreach loop from controller to view

Comment: read guide and learn more about MVC architecture. Your query run in model or controller and if you see in guide your foreach is in view... just look, read, try. Happy coding